# Why isn't haddock generating documentation?

Tags: haskell, documentation, haddock

My Haskell file (pretty sure this is not the problem) is basically:

```
import System.IO
...

-- | Every Word is a String
type Word = String

...

-- | Some documentation for Haddock to see
main :: IO ()
main = do
        ...
```

My `Setup.hs`:

```
import Distribution.Simple
main = defaultMain
```

My `grade.cabal`:

```
name:                grade
version:             0.1.0.0
...
build-type:          Simple
cabal-version:       >=1.8

executable grade
  main-is:             grade.hs
  -- other-modules:       
  build-depends:       base ==4.6.*, split ==0.2.*
  hs-source-dirs:      src
```

When I run `cabal haddock --executables` I get

```
...
Haddock coverage:
Warning: Not found in environment: Main.main
  50% (  1 /  2) in 'Main'
Warning: Main: could not find link destinations for:
    Main.main
Documentation created: dist/doc/html/grade/grade/index.html
```

and the HTML contains `main` but no documentation for it. It does not even contain functions I defined other than `main`. Why is that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add a module declaration to generate documents for it.

```
module Main (main, Word) where
```